# Is it possible to generate a separate file list when creating a tarball?

Tags: bash, backup, tar, io, stdout

When using `tar` for backups I'd like to create a separate list of the files that is included in the archive for storing alongside the backup tarball.

I also want to be able to store the error messages from tar in a log.

Solutions that's not so good:

- `tar --verbose` ... `&> filelist.txt` But this would give errors + file list in one file.
- `tar --list` after the tarball has been created. But this takes a long time.

Is there some way to get the file list and store it in a separate file at the same time as I'm rolling the ball for the first time?

Comment: how do you specify the files to `tar`?

Comment: Is getting a list separately before using tar an option?

Comment: Do you want only files or directories as well ? (`tar -v` is showing both)

Comment: Since `--list` also prints directories, what's the problem with `--verbose  [...] >filelist`

Comment: What makes --verbose a not-so-good option?  Did you consider `--index-file=FILE`

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. On my GNU tar 1.26, the only output of `tar -cvf foo.tar *` is the list of files. What is the "all output" that you want to avoid?

Comment: @terdon My problem was that I also needed a log with the error, I forgot to write that. My problem can be solved by either IO redirection or by some of the other tips suggested.

Comment: @Johan I suggest you make your suggestion an answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would put the error messages (`stderr`) in one file and file list (`stdout`) in one file:

```
$ tar -cvf archive.tar test nonexisting 1> stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt

$ cat stdout.txt
test/
test/05.txt
test/06.txt
test/00.txt
test/01.txt
test/10.txt
test/07.txt
test/03.txt
test/02.txt
test/04.txt
test/08.txt
test/09.txt

$ cat stderr.txt
tar: nonexisting: Funktion "stat" misslyckades: Filen eller katalogen finns inte
tar: Avslutar med felstatus på grund av tidigare fel
```

Using `--index-file` as suggested by Johan in the comment to my question would also work good:

```
tar --create \
    --verbose \
    --index-file=$fileList \
    --file $archiveFile \
    $filesystemToArchive \
    &>> $logFilename
```

From tar manpages:

> --index-file=FILE
>
> send verbose output to FILE

Answer (score 2):

You mention you don't like `tar --list` because it's slow. I'm guessing this is because it's a large tarball, and it has to re-scan the whole thing. If this is indeed the case, you can get better performance out of this by scanning as it's being created:

```
tar -c /input/directory | tee output.tar | tar -t > filelist.txt
```

This uses `tee` to split the resulting tarball, one going to a file, the other going to `tar -t`.

If you want to gzip the tarball:

```
tar -c /input/directory | tee >(gzip > output.tar.gz) | tar -t filelist.txt
```

We don't have the first `tar` do the gzip as it'll waste CPU cycles when the second tar has to decompress it again. Instead we only gzip the tarball as it's being written to disk.

Answer (score 1):

You could append each file to the tar file:

```
for f in file ...; do 
    echo "$f"
    tar rf result.tar $f
done
```